# Access nodes with edges to a certain node of interest in igraph python

Tags: python, igraph

I have an `igraph` graph object called `g` with some edges. I would like to get all nodes with an edge to a certain node

```
g = Graph.Tree(10, 2)
print g 

IGRAPH U--- 10 9 --
+ edges:
0--1 0--2 1--3 1--4 2--5 2--6 3--7 3--8 4--9
```

If I select node `1`, then I should get back a list of the other nodes with edges to node `1` (graph is undirected). The output should look like:

```
[0, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly what the `neighbors` method does.

```
g.neighbors(1)
Out[12]: [0, 3, 4]
```